# Can postman take environment values from the system environment variables?

Tags: api, security, postman, postman-collection-runner

As for security reasons i don't want to push username and password to my github account when i export the environment variables .json of postman , so i want to map the values or get the values from the environment variables of the running machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that Postman currently supports.

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1603

You're best bet would be to use a wrapper script to replace variables with usernames, passwords, etc at runtime.