# How to pass the Azure DevOps variables into Postman tests?

Tags: variables, testing, azure-devops, environment-variables, postman

I have a Postman collection exported as json and integrated into Azure DevOps pipelines. It currently uses a URL variable from the Postman environment exported as json.

I need to set the URL variable in Azure DevOps and use it in my Postman tests.

I have set the variable in the Command Line task for running tests (see the screenshot).

Question 1. I'm not sure if this is the correct place to set this variable.

Question 2. How do I pass the Azure variable into the Postman tests?

[image: Here's my screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to running postman test with a script, I also recommend that you use this out-of-the-box task：`Newman the cli Companion for Postman` from extension: [Newman the cli Companion for Postman](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=carlowahlstedt.NewmanPostman).

You can directly set the global variable in this task.

Yaml sample:

```
steps:
- task: NewmanPostman@4
  displayName: 'Newman - Postman'
  inputs:
    collectionFileSource: 'test1.postman_collection.json'
    environment: 'test.postman_environment.json'
    globalVars: 'aa=azuretest23'
    ignoreRedirect: false
    bail: false
    sslInsecure: false
    htmlExtraDarkTheme: false
    htmlExtraLogs: false
    htmlExtraTestPaging: false
```

You can hard code global variables directly, or you can use pipeline variables(e.g. `aa=$(var)`)
[image]

[image]

Using this task may make it easier for you to set environment variables and global variables.

**Update:**

Here is my example:

In Release Pipeline:

[image]

You could test the same settings in Postman and check if it could work.

In Postman:

[image]

`testurl` is `global variable`. `version` is `environment variable`.

Comment: Kevin, please see my response. I couldn't add screenshots to the comment

Comment: Hi @Pockemon. Since this error message does not contain many details, I couldn't determine the root cause of this issue. Can you execute the API in the PostMan Successfully? I have updated my answer and share more detail about the steps. Please check if it could give you some help.

Comment: On the other hand , the newman package version is 5.1.2. `npm install -g newman@5.1.2` You could try to install this version. If possible, you could also run the release stage in **Microsoft-hosted agent** (e.g. windows-2019) and check if it could work.

Comment: Kevin ,i'm new to azure.Can you share the full details about the Pipeline configuration for 'newman-postman' task?

Comment: Is it possible to give the global variable value set from Azure DevOps to a key value in the postman collection?

My set up is that I have my password in the Azure DevOps Library as a variable. I then use that variable to set the value of the globalvar in the yml with the NemanPostman@4 task. Then I want to get that globalvar value as a key value in my postman collection. I need that to get a token for further tests.

I have AAD-password declared in Azure, in yml I set the globalvars: 'Password=$(AAD-password)' and in the collection i use {{Password}} as value to give key the value.

Answer (score 0):

`Environment Variables` is a correct place if you inside of you scripts use syntax like `$env:url` (for powershell for instance) and from what I found this is not possible. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52965425/can-postman-take-environment-values-from-the-system-environment-variables)

But you can pass variable like it is shown [here](https://community.postman.com/t/how-to-pass-argument-or-value-while-running-collection-from-newman/7417) or [here](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/764)

`newman run -g environment.json --global-var "foo=$(YOURVARIABLE)"`

So you should go to variables tab and there define this variable and use as above ot paste url instead of `$(YOURVARIABLE)`

Comment: Thank you so much. So if I use -e for the environment, shall I use --env-var instead of --global-var?

**newman run MyCollection.json -e MyEnvironment.json --env-var "url=$(url)" --reporters cli,junit --reporter-junit-export Results/junitReport.xml**